# Cannot connect HCP Vault with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to connect HCP Vault with AWS EKS, without success though.

Steps I'm doing:

1. I've configured HVN and peered it with VPC where my k8s cluster is located.
2. Created HCP Vault cluster in that HVN.
3. Created injector pod via Helm
4. Because Vault Cluster is private only I'm using bastion host to connect to it using this instruction: https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404774536083-Accessing-private-URLs-of-HCP-Clusters
5. From a bastion host: `vault auth enable kubernetes`
6. I've created service account **admin-panel** in the namespace **admin panel**
7. I'm exporting some values from my namespace...
8. `export TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT=$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount admin-panel -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') -o jsonpath='{ .data.token }' | base64 --decode)`
9. `export KUBE_CA_CERT=$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount admin-panel -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') -o jsonpath='{ .data.ca\.crt }' | base64 --decode)`
10. `export KUBE_HOST=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.server}')`
11. ...in order to configure auth method: `vault write auth/kubernetes/config token_reviewer_jwt="$TOKEN_REVIEW_JWT" kubernetes_host="$KUBE_HOST" kubernetes_ca_cert="$KUBE_CA_CERT"`
12. I finally enabled auth engine and created a secret: `vault secrets enable -path=secret kv-v2` and `vault kv put secret/admin-panel/config username=‘user’ password=‘password’`
13. We need some policy:

```
`vault policy write admin-panel - <<EOF     
 path "secret/data/admin-panel/config" {     
   capabilities = ["read"]     
 }
 EOF`
```

13. And authetication role: `vault write auth/kubernetes/role/admin-panel bound_service_account_names=admin-panel bound_service_account_namespaces=admin-panel policies=admin-panel ttl=24h`
14. Finally I want to use it in the pod:

    ```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: test
      labels:
        app: test
    annotations:
      vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
      vault.hashicorp.com/role: "admin-panel"
      vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-credentials.txt: "secret/data/admin-panel/config"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: admin-panel
      containers:
        - name: test
          image: nginx
    ```

I'm getting typically error:

```
    2022-08-30T21:57:18.366Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:
  error=
  | Error making API request.
  | 
  | URL: PUT https://vault-cluster-private-vault-dflosi.hfols.z1.hashicorp.cloud:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
  | Code: 403. Errors:
  | 
  | * permission denied
   backoff=3m48.31s
2022-08-30T22:01:06.685Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2022-08-30T22:01:06.703Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating:
  error=
  | Error making API request.
```

I'm following the official tutorial, what am I missing?

Comment: Vault tutorials typically are missing a step or two, and may also have an inaccurate step. If you purchased HCP Vault, then you would have a support contract I would imagine. You can probably use that.

Answer (score 0):

Something I notice here that might be the issue is that you bound service account only in namespace `admin-panel` while vault role creation but you're
creating the `pod` in the default namespace, where the service account is not configured to authenticate with EKS.

Either try creating the pod in the `admin-panel` namespace or change `bound_service_account_namespaces` to * while configuring vault role.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the error stays the same